# playwright integration with Selenium Grid

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid, playwright, playwright-python

I have started using playwright automation tool from last few weeks, I want to understand, Is it possible to run playwright test using selenium grid? how I can point my test cases to grid hub endpoint using playwright?

In case of selenium we simply use RemoteWebdriver but I am not finding similar option in playwright.

Comment: do you have any update on this? Im still trying to figure out how to run my test on selenium grid and change to configuration programatically if I want to run locally or remotely like using Selenium

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is. You can use [BrowserType.connect_over_cdp()](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/api/class-browsertype#browser-type-connect-over-cdp) to connect to your existing Chromium browsers over the Chrome DevTools Protocol. But this has the downside that you can't use WebKit or Firefox with it.